# Int64 for enumerated loops

Tags: swift

If I use `array.enumerated` I can loop over int indices. But

`for (intIndex, actionElement) in actionElements.enumerated()`

But what if I want to use Int64 instead of Int?
What is the best syntax of that?
BTW, currently, I simply use this: `let index = Int64(intIndex)`

Comment: Are you are that `Int` _is_ `Int64` on 64-bit machines?

Comment: I know @Sweeper . Nonetheless, these types are different.

Comment: Arrays are indexed by `Int`, so why does it make sense to enumerate it with `Int64` indices? Are you just trying to pass the index to some function that needs an `Int64`? In that case converting using `Int64.init` (i.e. what you are doing) is fine.

Comment: Yes. But I want to make this code be correct for 32-bits too. If compilator says, "they are different", I want to make cast it correct for each platform

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why would you not want natively sized integers? And what's wrong with `Int64(intIndex)`? I mean, I can make it a _little_ nicer by doing `.enumerated().map { (Int64($0), $1) }`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Currently, this code depends on the architecture. This isn't the correct solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213555/discussion-between-sweeper-and-vyacheslav).

Comment: @Sweeper you solution doesn't properly work for 32-architecture

Comment: `Int32.max` is `4.294.967.295`. Do your arrays contain more items? If not `Int` works exactly the same way on 32 and 64 bit machines. There is no reason to use `Int64` explicitly.

Comment: @vadian nonetheless, it seems, such behavior is a disadvantage of the language. In the chat, I've explained my idea

Comment: In my opinion it's not. In 99% of the cases `Int` is perfectly fine for both architectures (like `NSInteger` in Objective-C for more than 10 years). If you need an overload for a special case write an extension.

Comment: @vadian but code should work not for 99%, excuse me

Comment: Right but as you – the developer – have to prevent out-of-range and unexpected found `nil` exceptions you have to prevent the integer overflow. The language can not handle everything on your behalf.

Comment: So I can't predict out-of-bound for 32arch without an extra check (whether 32 bit)

Comment: Yes, you can't, but you are supposed to predict that the number of items in the array won't exceed `Int32.max`. If you really can't predict use `stride` with `Int64` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the types to what you want them to be:

```
for (index, actionElement) in actionElements.enumerated().map({(Int64($0), $1)}) { ... }
```

You say you want indices, however. `enumerated` doesn't return indices. It returns offsets. For an Array, those happen to be the same, but this isn't universally true, and it's easy to have this turn into a bug if you do something like add `dropFirst()`. If you really want indices, you can zip them the same way:

```
for (index, actionElement) in zip(actionElements.indices.map(Int64.init), actionElements) { ... }
```

In both of these cases, the syntax gets a bit long, so I'd break it up into a separate variable, or create a helper function, but in any case the solution is going to be to map all the values, or to convert them when you use them (as you're currently doing).

Comment: does zip behave like an iterator?

Comment: I mean, the idea is nice, but it can consume a lot of memory

Comment: Yes, zip is an iterator. I'm not sure why you would expect this to consume a lot of memory. `map` does create a second array, but you can add `.lazy` and remove that if you expect actionElements to be large (for very small lists, it can potentially prevent other optimizations). `zip` does not create a second array.